# How choose MPU for image streaming and transmission

Tags: arm, wifi, imageprocessing

I want to ask how to choose and how much processing power are required to be able to stream video using a wifi module. I'll explain better; I have a camera sensor of 5Mpx, i want to elaborate video from this sensor and stream it through a wifi module.

My question is: how can i correctly choose an MPU and a wifi module to be able to do that?(considering that i can choose lower image quality)

My first intention was to use an integrated module Cortex-M3 120MHz 128KB RAM with wifi, but the productor said me that is hard to transfer image or video due to the throughput limitation of SPI/URAT interface.

What can you advice me?

EDIT:
As I see online I will need a configuration like this:
Sensor->decoder->MPU->wifi

That's right? Someone can advice me a decoder or mpu+decoder able to do that?

Comment: You'll want something with a camera interface that matches your module, such as MIPI.

Answer (score 2):

> camera sensor of 5Mpx, i want to elaborate video from this sensor and stream it through a wifi module [...]
>   use an integrated module Cortex-M3 120MHz 128KB RAM with wifi

The 5MPx picture requires 5 MegaBytes (!) of RAM to be stored only.
Thus you need much beefier equipment. Video compression is *really* computational expensive.

I would strongy suggest using some ARM SoC board with Linux/Android, like the ones inside mobile phones. Look for somthing that fits your camera sensor's interface.